# Xbee Stops Searching For Coordinator?

Tags: timeout, verification, channel, watchdog, xbee

I'm trying to assamble a healty communication between two Xbee modules. I've succedd what I want but there's a problem that I couldn't figure out.
There are 2 parameters in X-CTU which makes me confused.

### JV - Channel Verification

### NW - Network Watchdog Timeout

I've read all instructions from datasheet, I've googled many times but I couldn't find any significant solution. What is my problem? I'm working on some "worst cases". For now, the worst case for me is starting of router before loooong looong time from starting of coordinator. I've solved this problem by setting JV = 0 and NW = 1. But if I set JV = 1, NW = 1, and if I started coordinator long time (for ex. half an hour) after router, router does not trying to find coordinator. Why is this happening? I couldn't understand what's going on in Xbee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JV parameter will cause an XBee Router node to search for its Coordinator upon power-up (and only on power-up!).  If it does not find the Coordinator it will leave the current network and channel its on and go looking around for another Coordinator it can join.

The NW parameter is like the JV parameter but more agressive: it will cause the XBee Router to leave the network if it doesn't hear from the Coordinator in NW * 3 minutes.

If you have set JV=1 and NW=10 on your XBee router then the XBee will search for its Coordinator on power up and check to see that it has spoke with the Coordinator at least once in 30 minutes.  If it either can't find the Coordinator or if it hasn't spoken to the Coordinator, it will cause the Router to leave the network and look for another network to join.

If your XBee Router is unable to find the Coordinator any longer have a look at the Coordinators NJ parameter.  NJ must be set to 0xff (255) to always allow joining.  Otherwise if NJ < 255, it cause the Coordinator to disable joining from nodes after NJ seconds.  For example, if you set NJ to 60 then Routers will only be able to join the network 60 seconds after the Coordinator has created the network.  This parameter is normally set for security reasons where the network has been deployed and you want to make absolutely positive that nobody else can join.

If all else fails feel free to ask your question in the Digi XBee ZB forum: http://forums.digi.com/support/forum/listthreads?forum=5